I can help the people confused about Melchizedek?
First Who is Melchizedek -
If the spirit of wisdom has not come over you about it; it’s because your trying to hard my brotha’s.
Melchizedek is the most High duh!
It’s said in the word Hebrews 7:3: "Without father or mother, without genealogy, having neither beginning of days nor end of life, but made like unto the Son of God; abideth a priest continually" Melchizedek has no beginning of days nor end of life right? Who does that sound like ? Hm?
** Revelation 22:13 states, "I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End,"**
Again just in case your doubting-
Isaiah 9:6, which says, “For to us a child is born, to us a son is given, and the government will be on his shoulders. And he will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father,PRINCE OF PEACE”.
(Prince of peace right?)That’s Jesus.
2 To whom also Abraham gave a tenth part of all; first being by interpretation (KING OF RIGHTOUSNESS), and after that also King of Salem, which is,(Melchizedek is KING OF PEACE!)
Abraham gave a tenth of every thing to Melchizedek right ?
The Bible verse that most directly refers to "paying 10 percent to the Lord" is Leviticus 27:30, which states: "A tithe of everything from the land, whether grain from the soil or fruit from the trees, belongs to the Lord; it is holy to the Lord" - essentially meaning that a tenth of one's produce should be set aside as a tithe for God.
Just so happen the first time tithes were given in history was from Abram to Melchizedek !? Just so happen to be 10 percent we all be doing it since that day.

I’m voting to close this question because This is a statement and not a question.

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Hope dottard doesn’t close it then take my info as his !!?

I am not sure you can claim this as "your info" as it is readily available in the Scripture.  The word "Melchizedek" means "King of righteouness"  The fact that he was also king of Salem also means he was also "king of peace" as the explicit statements in Heb 7:2.  He was also priest of the Most High God. Heb 7:1, Gen 14:19.  See also Heb 5:10, etc.  All this is well documented in the Scripture.

Well I'm still confused so can you please unconfuse me and tell me directly who is Melchizedek? If your claiming he is Jesus Christ then how do you explain that Jesus had a father and mother?

@Mr.Bond And Jesus' father was . . . .  ?

@Nigel  I was being "facetious" with my question Nigel. As you should know Melchizedek is not Jesus Christ.

@Mr.Bond That is the point, sir. We do not know whom he is. And yes, it could be a manifestation. Though not, of course, an incarnation.
